# Limit of Integral of sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I could not find any way to solve this question.

Let $\{ a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\, a_n = \alpha >0$, and let $f(x)$ be real-valued continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=k$. Compute
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{- a_n  x} dx.$$

Comment: I do not know why the question has been closed while it has not been solved yet! Please I need the solution so bad. Thank you very much.